# How can I use the androids' music stream as the data source of the media player library

Tags: android

In my app, I am trying to alter the volume of both(left/right headphone music streams) coming out of the device with a Seekbar.

The AudioManager Class can access the music stream coming from the device:

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxValue = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int curValue = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

But the AudioManager .setStreamVolume() class can only change the volume coming from both ears together.

I figured out how to set the volume separately with the MediaPlayer class but how do I link the MediaPlayer class's .setDataSource() method to the stream coming out of the android device?

I looked everywhere and still haven't found an answer. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You use [setAudioStreamType()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)) after you `setDataSource()`, but before calling
`prepare`

Comment: So what should I put as the arguments inside setDataSource () in order for the data source to be the music coming from the phone such as from Pandora or spotify?

Comment: I apologize, I seem to have misunderstood your question. You can't use the stream type as an input source for the `MediaPlayer`. It is output only. If you are trying to play music from services such as Pandora or Spotify, the you will need to see if they offer an SDK. They will more than likely have their own Player calls for use with their service.